# How i can change current date not all just days?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want change the current date or i want put variable in current date like this:

```
$companyDates = $company_dates['dates']; //this variable come from DataBase
$databaseDate=DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $companyDates);
$day=$databaseDate->format('d'); // this is how i take just days from date format(y-m-d)

$dt = new DateTime();
$today = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$oldDate=$dt->format('Y-m-$day'); // here i want days from database into current day month and year.
```

and then i want to find different day like this:

```
$date1=date_create($today);
$date2=date_create($oldDate);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

Is this possible OR is this my way right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:Use `setDate`

```
$day=10;
$dt = new DateTime();
$today = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$out = new DateTime();
$out->setDate($out->format('Y'), $out->format('m'), $day);
$oldDate= $out->format('Y-m-d');
$d1=new DateTime($oldDate);$d2=new DateTime($today);
$difference = $d1->diff($d2);
echo $difference->format('%r%a days');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass desired day inside format

```
$oldDate=$dt->format('Y-m-$day');
```

It's wrong format (and if you want to concatenate string with variable you should use double `quote(")` instead of `single(')`)

Use `setDate()` method instead of.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$oldDate = clone $today; // Clone instead creating new instance because two different DateTime instances may have different dates
$oldDate->setDate($oldDate->format('Y'), $oldDate->format('m'), $day);
```